# Как правильно говорить "не получил верное решение" или "не получил верного решения"?

Tags: семантика

Правильно ли использовать в данном предложении слово "получил"? Или же более грамотно использовать слово "нашел"?
Если возможно, дайте, пожалуйста, развернутое пояснение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Когда что-то пытаются решить, ИЩУТ пути решения. А  по завершении поиска НАХОДЯТ. Работает пара ИСКАТЬ - НАХОДИТЬ.

**Не нашёл верного решения, не нашёл верное решение.**

Comment: С этим ясно, спасибо. Я столкнулся с утверждением, что выражение "Не нашел верного решения" звучит безграмотно. Дескать правильно говорить "не нашел верное решение". Поясните, пожалуйста, почему.

Comment: http://www.knowed.ru/index.php?id=890&name=pages&op=view - почитайте здесь.Родительный падеж, имеющий значение подчеркнутого отрицания, обычно употребляется: 
3) при глаголах восприятия, мысли, желания, ожидания 
4) при глаголах иметь, получать, доставать и т. п., которые в сочетании с частицей не приобретают значение полного отрицания, например: не имеет комнаты, не получил приказа, не достал билета, не приобрёл нужных вещей.  Я не получал подарка; я не нашёл решения.
5) при выражении дополнения отвлеченным существительным - у Вас отвлечённое сущ.

Answer (score 0):

```
 При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно преобладает употребление дополнения в родительном падеже , в других – употребление дополнения в винительном падеже, в третьих – наблюдается факультативное их использование. 
 Факультативное употребление родительного и винительного падежа при переходном глаголе с отрицанием связано со стилистическим различием: конструкции с РОДИТЕЛЬНЫМ падежом характерны для КНИЖНОЙ речи, конструкции с ВИНИТЕЛЬНЫМ падежом – для речи РАЗГОВОРНОЙ: Например, я не умаляю чьих-либо заслуг. Сравните: так и умрешь, не выговорив это слово. 
 Кроме того, вполне возможно и уместно использование оборота "найти верное решение ". Таким образом, "не нашёл верного решения" - с глаголом "найти" и сущ. "решения" в родительном падеже.
```